# building a windows file search application

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code

So I am tasked with organizing possibly hundreds of CT scans for my uni project. The CT scan files will have varying degrees of different properties that we will manually assign and the idea is to simplify the process of finding appropriate files with specified properties quickly and accurately. The proposed idea was to just maintain an excel file for manual lookup.

But I am thinking of making a very simple windows app with sliders and checkboxes that will scour the entire file tree with nested folders and show the correct files in the app window that then could be drag and dropped and such. The solution has to be user friendly so barebones script-based solution won't do.

From the little research I have done, I have come across some corporate-based solutions for automated document classification. And there isn't really a comprehensive solution to having custom persistent file metadata, which is what I had in mind. Maybe maintaining some kind of lookup table for the application is the better way.

Is there anyone experienced who could steer me in the right direction and give me some advice and pointers? Or am I better off going with some other already existing solution? Currently my CS knowledge is very theoretical and I haven't really messed around with windows app development. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're not allowed to use any third-party frameworks then  _"a very simple windows app with sliders and checkboxes"_ may turn out to be an absolute marvel of ancient technology by the time you finish it.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure I'm overlooking a lot of intricacies. I would love to hear about some already existing frameworks that could be utilized, I'm just not too sure about what and how of it. I didn't find any applications that could be suitable for this use case. I imagine the search criterea would be a few dozen at most, so in theory seemed quite simple to me. Any kind of inputs and leads to pursue would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Are these properties part of the CT scan files, or are they separate metadata that you're trying to track? Additionally, are you expecting to be able to open the CT scans in another program directly from the file browser, or are you expecting to need to open them through your program before use in whatever viewer you'd be using?

Comment: So the properties we're trying to base the searching on will be manually initialized after human inspection(level of noise, artifacts etc). My hope is to append that information somehow as some sort of metadata(but I think this isn't very viable and consistent when it comes to multiple machines or transferring of those files) or just have some centralized lookup table somewhere. 
And once the searched files are found the program doesn't have to do anything more, they'll be drag and dropped into another program that handles opening up the CT scans.